# Return variable from its name in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, variables

Say I have a variable `var=1` and a string `str='var'`.
How can I obtain the value of `var` from `str`?. I tried using `str2num(str)`, but it didn't work.

Also, if I had 2 strings `str1='some letters'` and `str2='str1'`, can I obtaing the phase 'some letters' from `str2`?

I want to do this because I have many matrices (quite big) and I want to separate them in some groups, so I thought about making cells with the names of each of the matrices that belong to a group (a matrix can belong to more than one group, so making cells with the matrices is not very good).

Comment: If you had the matrices themselves in a cell array, then each "group" would just need to be a vector/matrix of indices into that array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
x = eval( str ) ;
```

But it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Though it can easily be achieved with an `eval` as [@Shai mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815620/1714410), you probably don't really want to do this. Using `eval` hinders your debugging and depending on the name of variables seriously limits the flexibility of your code. If you want to name something, you may be better off using a struct with a data field and a name field instead.

Judging from your description, I wonder about the following:

#### 1. Why do you have many matrices?

For each variable that you have, you depend on a name. Depending on a lot of names is typically undesirable. Hence my suggestion:

> Use a (cell) array containing these matrices

#### 2. What way do you exactly want them to be in a group

It is not clear to me how you want the grouping to work, but think of this:

> If you want to use names, create a struct or array of structs with a `nameField`, but
>   otherwise just use a cell array and have each matrix get a number.

You can now handle the matrices more easily and things like 'selecting 10 random matrices' or 'selecting all matrices whose `nameField` contains 'abc'' can be done easily and efficiently.

You can now also have a field with your data specifying in which groups it is, or you can define groups as simple lists of numbers.